# Custom Lambda Authorizer Event Payload type

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am trying to create a custom lambda authorizer with the lambda event payload type as "REQUEST".
the serverless.yml is pretty simple

```
functions:
  authorizer:
    handler: src/authorizer.handler
    type: REQUEST
```

Whenever I deploy this yaml file it creates an authorizer with a TOKEN-based Event Payload instead of REQUEST-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authorizer type should be set below the `events` section, like this:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http: 
          path: /hello
          method: get
          authorizer:
            name: authorizer
            type: request
            
        
  authorizer:
    handler: authorizer.handler
```

You have instead specified the type next to "handler" on the function itself. Serverless deploys with a warning if you do this "Warning: Invalid configuration encountered
at 'functions.authorizer': unrecognized property 'type'". It then defaults to "token" as type since no valid type was found.